# Mandatory Querystring parameter for AWS Lambda using SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have an API endpoint calling a lambda function. In its simplest form, here is the template file section for it:

```yaml
Resources:
  GetS3ObjectsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: GetS3Objects
      Description: SAM Kata for S3 Access
      CodeUri: get_s3_objects/
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        GetS3ObjectsAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /GetS3Objects
            Method: get
            RequestParameters:
              - method.request.querystring.bucket:
                  Required: true
```

This is the best I can find from the documentation. however, neither local and nor stack deployment put any restriction on the endpoint, i.e. the lambda will be called no matter a query string is supplied or not, or it has a bucket or not.

Is this the expected behavior? can I do something so that the API gateway will reject the request if bucket is not specified in the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

Setting `Required: true` on a parameter in `RequestParameters` does not currently cause a validator to be applied to the `GET` API endpoint created for an `AWS::Serverless::Function`.

### Workaround

Create a placeholder `Model` and add `RequestModel` to the function.

Within `RequestModel` validate the parameters but do not validate the placeholder body:

```yaml
Resources:
# ---------- API ----------
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      ...
      Models:
        ...
        ValidationWorkaroundBody:
          type: object
          title: placeholder model to enable RequestParameters validation workaround
          properties:
            optional_property:
              type: string
      ...
  # ---------- Lambda Functions ----------
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      ...
      Events:
        MyApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            ...
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            RequestParameters:
            - method.request.querystring.myparam:
                Caching: false
                Required: true
            RequestModel:
              Model: ValidationWorkaroundBody
              Required: true
              ValidateBody: false # don't validate the workaround body
              ValidateParameters: true # only validate the request parameters
```

This will apply a `params-only` validator to the API endpoint which will enforce the parameters specified in `RequestParameters` (and simply ignore the placeholder `Model`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should be able to get the result with a WAF rule

API GW Documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html

WAF Rules - A string match or an regex pattern match on the
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statements-list.html

You should be able to match the query string or a single parameter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-fields.html#waf-rule-statement-request-component